# Query builder filter based on related records sum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms, laravel-query-builder

I would appreciate some help regarding laravel/octobercms query builder.
I have two models/tables as follows:

CV model has many Experiences, Experience model belongs to CV.

```
CVs table  
| id | user_id |  
| --- | ------ |  
| 1 | 11 |  
| 2 | 22 |  



Experiences table  
| id | cv_id | from | to |  
| --- | ------ | ----- | --- |  
| 1 | 1 | 2019-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |  
| 2 | 1 | 2020-05-02 | 2021-09-01 |   
| 3 | 2 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-05-01 |  
| 4 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-05-01 |
```

I'm trying to use query builder to filter CV's based on Experiences duration. For example, CV with id: 2, has two experiences with id 3 and 4, each with 4 moths of experience, so in total CV with id: 2 has 8 months of experience.

So far I tried variations of:

```
$query = Cv::query()->whereHas('experiences', function ($query) {
        $query->addSelect(DB::raw("SUM(DATEDIFF(COALESCE(`to`, CURDATE()), `from`)) AS sum_experience"));
    });
```

Above produces:

```
select * from `cvs` where exists (select *, SUM(DATEDIFF(COALESCE(`to`, CURDATE()), `from`)) AS sum_experience from `cv_expriences` where `cvs`.`id` = `cv_expriences`.`cv_id`)
```

But I don't know how can I compare sum_experience value, to a value I need.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would like to give one suggestion if it's possible, you should calculate experience in a month while adding/updating it ... and add it directly to the CV table,  it will make things really easy for you to manage and search from it as well as less complex DB query will increase response time ...

Comment: it may sound redundant but when you scale your project, these queries will be troublesome ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking about this as last solution. Maybe I should have consider it as first.

Comment: it would be best as it will make your life lot easier and queries will be super simple :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can just `calculate experience in a month` while adding/updating records of the `Experiences table` and add it directly to the `CV table`.

> It will make things really easy for you to manage and search from it as well as `less complex` DB queries will increase response time

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: The problem with this solution, is that sometimes the 'to' columns might be 'null'. In such cases the current date matters. I've delayed this issue at the moment, I'll comment when I have a working solution.

Comment: so you can just calculate based on current data and fill data I guess ...